# How to have multiple build flavors with stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

When developing, I want to build everything with `-O0` to save time.

But when building the same package on a CI system, I want to use `-O`.

One option I see would be to have two different `stack.yaml` files differing in their `ghc-options`, but then I'd have to make all changes to `stack.yaml` in two places.

Having an alias for `stack --ghc-options=-O0` doesn't work, because I want `-O0` to apply only to local packages, not the snapshot, and there's no way to specify that on the command line, from what I know.

Are there any better options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `stack build --ghc-options=-O0` will apply -O0 to only the local packages, not to the snapshot packages. For more information, see:

https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/GUIDE.md#ghc-options

Comment: Thanks, good to know. So would this be the recommended solution for unoptimized builds?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I do during development.